# Touchpad super sensitive after shutdown during game

Tags: xorg, wine, mouse, touchpad

- I was playing a game via WINE called Artemis.
- I ran out of battery power and my computer immediately shut down because my power manager currently doesn't work.
- Now my touchpad is super sensitive in every desktop environment, to the extent that it's extremely frustrating to type because the cursor jumps everywhere.

PLEASE SAVE ME

I've tried reducing the mouse sensitivity in Unity and KDE and it changes nothing. I typically use i3 and haven't figured out how to disable the touchpad in i3. I want disabling the touchpad to be a last resort though, because I actually use it more often than the mouse.

I tagged xorg because this happens across various DEs

Answer (score 0):

I installed a GUI for the synaptiks driver - the `touchpad-indicator` package.

This allowed me to turn off cursor acceleration which, for whatever reason, KDE and Unity failed to do with the nature of my problem.

I'm unsure if I've really fixed my problem or just patched around it, but in any case, my laptop is operable again.